# Array to store connection between other arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of unique Element IDs and Node IDs and an array which stores which Element contains which Nodes. The Number of nodes_IDs per Element_IDs may vary between 3-20, but within one array it is constant :

```
Elements = np.array(([ 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...,, Node_ID_k],
                     [ 2, 6, 1, 4, 5, ...,, Node_ID_k],
                     [...]
                     [Element_ID, Node_ID_1, Nodes_ID_2, ..., Node_ID_k]
```

Now I need to connect those two entities quite often: 
For example to get the location of the elements I have to look up the coordinates by the Node_ID. Then I calculate something and want to store it for each node. So I need the connecting which element contains which nodes and then Vis versa which elements belong to a Node ID.

Of the large list of Nodes

```
Nodes = [Node_ID 1, Node_ID 2,Node_ID 3, ... , Node_ID 120000]
```

I have a subset of Nodes(for example 100 out of 120 000):

```
Nodeset = [ Node_ID 1, ..., Node_ID 100]
```

I found the entries from the "Elements" array, which contain the IDs of "Nodeset" with the following code:

```
import numpy as np

def getbyfnodes(Nodeset,  Elements):

    #nodes per element 
    npe = 4

    #mask
    mask_element = np.zeros((Elements.shape[0]), dtype = bool)
    mask_nodes = np.zeros_like(Elements[:,1:], dtype = bool)

    for i,column in enumerate(Elements[:,1:].T): #check colum wise 
        mask_nodes[:,i]  = np.in1d(column, Nodeset)

    mask_element = mask_nodes.sum( axis = 1 )  == npe  #only elements with 'npe' nodes

    #reduced size row wise   
    mask_nodes = mask_nodes[mask_element,:] # reduce Nodes mask for Relevant elements

    # Node_ID, Element_ID 1, 2, 3, 4
    Set_elements = np.zeros((len(Nodeset),npe + 1 ))
    Set_elements[:,0] = Nodeset

    for i,row in enumerate(Elements[mask_element,1:]):
        Set_elements[i,:] = row[mask_nodes[i,:]] 

    return Set_elements
```

How do I get the other way round?
I want to have an array which list the Node IDs of the "Nodeset" first and then which Element IDs belong to that node:

```
Nodes = np.array(( [Node_ID 1 , Element_ID_1, Element_ID_2, ..., Element_ID_k],  
                   [...],  
                   [Node_ID 100 , Element_ID_1, Element_ID_2, ..., Element_ID_k]))
```

Ideally I want to have an array which stores the connection or pointer of

> Element 1 contains Node 1 , Node 2, Node 3 and Node 4
>   Node 1 is part of Element 1 , Element 5 , Element 8 and Element 9

Using such thing would make it easier to use data from one set to calculate something for the other set!

Comment: If the question / problem is not clear please let me know, i am very unsure aboute the title matching the actual problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just using a hashmap (or more than one) that does what you need in terms of mapping. That way you are getting O(1) in retrieving the relations (of course setting up and updating the data structure will probably be quadratic or something like that).

Comment: As far as I understand, you intend to use a dictonary to store the relationship between Elements and its nodes, respectively their location in the list of nodes? E.g : dic = { Element_ID_1 : [Node_ID_1,Node_ID_2,Node_ID_3, ..] , Element_ID_1 : [...],...}

Comment: If it is applicable in your scenario, yes. Otherwise this is a graph implementation.